# Selenium - trapped in an iframe

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to navigate to the parent frame of a frame containing a tinymce that i navigated to through:

driver.switchTo().frame(1);
I have attempted to use driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); to navigate back to the parent but it isn't working, it's not throwing any errors, it just refuses to recognize any webElement that I know is on the parent page.

The webdriver returns no iframes found after I have navigated to the tinymce's frame.

```
    final List<WebElement> iframes = driver.findElements(By
            .tagName("iframe"));


    System.out.println(iframes);

    //console: [] (an empty List)
```

This the code prior, and post, to the navigation:

```
    driver.findElement(
            By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'ask_answer_link')]"))
            .click();

    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.switchTo().frame(1);
    WebElement i = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#tinymce"));

    JavascriptExecutor js = null;
    if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
        js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    }
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = '<p>" + msg + "</p>'", i);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
```

This the document that is nested inside of the main html document, I cannot get out of it:

```
<!DOCTYPE >
<html style="overflow-y: hidden;" webdriver="true">
    <head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></head>
    <body id="tinymce" class="mceContentBody " contenteditable="true" onload="window.parent.tinyMCE.get('ask_answer_field_92693607040').onLoad.dispatch();" style="overflow-y: hidden; padding-bottom: 50px;" dir="ltr">
        <p></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Tried everything I can think of, I am still trapped in the tinymce's frame.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited. I did edit the post probably did not save.**

Did you try the following? when you are done working inside the frame just simply use the following line in a suitable place and that should set focus to the default content

```
Driver.SwitchTo().Window(Driver.WindowHandles.FirstOrDefault());
```